# checkbox to mysql in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

how to save checkbox value to database ?

my view code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id={{$cat->id}} value={{$cat->id}}>
```

my controller code:

```
    public function submitArticle(){
    $article = new Post();
    $article->title= Input::get('title');
    $article->body= Input::get('body');
    $article->cat = Input::get('checkbox');
    $article->save();
    $articleId = $article->id;
    return $articleId;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Should be the same as any other data you insert. Is there a particular issue you have with this field?

Comment: yes,my problem with checkbox @Goose

Comment: I don't understand. I know you have a problem with checkbox, but what have you tried? What behavior do you get with checkbox that you don't get with other inputs?

Comment: edited question @Goose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id={{$cat->id}} value={{$cat->id}}>
```

and in controller

```
if(is_array($checkbox)){
        $relationCategory = $checkbox;
        foreach ($relationCategory as $relCat){
            $rel = new Relationship();
            $rel->post_id = $articleId;
            $rel->cat_id = $relCat;
            $rel->save();
        }
    }
```